Azure Pipelines - Test results run comparison
I have some automated tests that run as part of an azure release pipeline and am trying to compare the results output from one release to another. The overall test summary give a good overall indication of pass rate etc

but im specifically trying to compare which tests began failing in a specific release vs an earlier release where they may have been passing.
Currently im having to manually compare the failed tests between releases which is not an officiant approach.
Does anyone know if there's a way to compare the results of specific tests between two different releases?

Not sure if I understand your problem - the Failing since and Failing release columns in your screenshot are not what you're looking for?

I am afraid that there is no out-of-box method can support compare the results of specific tests between two different releases.
Currently, there is no built-in feature or extension in Azure DevOps that can compare specific test information between different releases.
For a workaround, you can consider using Rest API to get the test result of the release pipelines for comparison .
Here are the Rest APIs:
Get Release test ID:
Get https://vstmr.dev.azure.com/{Org}/{Project}/_apis/testresults/resultdetailsbyrelease?releaseId={release id}&releaseEnvId={release environment id}&api-version=5.2-preview.1

Results - Get
Here is script example:
$token = "PAT"

$releaseId1 = releaseid1

$releaseEnvId1 = env1

$releaseId2 = releaseid2

$releaseEnvId2 = env2

$organizationame = "orgname"

$projectname ="projectname"


$testnames = @("testmethodname1","testmethod2")

#checkrelease1

$url="https://vstmr.dev.azure.com/$($organizationame)/$($projectname)/_apis/testresults/resultdetailsbyrelease?releaseId=$($releaseId1)&releaseEnvId=$($releaseEnvId1)&api-version=5.2-preview.1"

$token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get  -ContentType application/json


$testresultID = $response.resultsForGroup[0].results[0].id

$testrunID = $response.resultsForGroup[0].results[0].testrun.id

$urlgettestdetails = "https://dev.azure.com/$($organizationame)/$($projectname)/_apis/test/Runs/$($testrunID)/results/$($testresultID)?api-version=7.1-preview.6"

$responsegettestdetails = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $urlgettestdetails -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get  -ContentType application/json


foreach($testname in $testnames)
{


  foreach($testresult in $responsegettestdetails)
  {
     if($testresult.testcase.name -eq $testname)
     {
        echo "The testmethod:$testname is $($testresult.outcome) in releaseID: $releaseId1"
     }
  }

}

#checkrelease2

$url1="https://vstmr.dev.azure.com/$($organizationame)/$($projectname)/_apis/testresults/resultdetailsbyrelease?releaseId=$($releaseId2)&releaseEnvId=$($releaseEnvId2)&api-version=5.2-preview.1"


$response1 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url1 -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get  -ContentType application/json


$testresultID = $response1.resultsForGroup[0].results[0].id

$testrunID = $response1.resultsForGroup[0].results[0].testrun.id

$urlgettestdetails2 = "https://dev.azure.com/$($organizationame)/$($projectname)/_apis/test/Runs/$($testrunID)/results/$($testresultID)?api-version=7.1-preview.6"

$responsegettestdetails2 = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $urlgettestdetails2 -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Get  -ContentType application/json


foreach($testname in $testnames)
{


  foreach($testresult in $responsegettestdetails2)
  {
     if($testresult.testcase.name -eq $testname)
     {
        echo "The testmethod:$testname is $($testresult.outcome) in releaseID: $releaseId2"
     }
  }

}

You can change the comparison content according to your requirements.
On the other hand, you can use the Test Results Trend widget in Dashboard to monitor the changes between release.
I can fully understand your requirement. You can submit a suggest ticket in the site: Developer Community to report this feature.
